# Row retrieval error

Tags: php, mysql

I've been working on a gallery project and I've come to a stand-still with this error. Basically when a user visits image.php?id=37 for example, it retrieves all of the row information from the images table where the row id equals the url parameter. All of this has worked well as for the actual image url being retrieved, the gallery id and image id. I'm now trying to incorporate a description into this page which also is retrieved from the images table. I've gone ahead and added the column, entered a few test descriptions in and added the code to my PHP page as I have been doing successfully over the past few days and I get this error:

Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc FROM images WHERE id = 37' at line 5

I fail to see what has gone wrong as nothing sticks out as being different to past attempts :L.

My image.php page:

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
    <div class="image" style="background: url('resources/galleries/images/<?php echo htmlentities($row['url'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>') no-repeat; background-size: 100%; ">
        <? if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) { } else { print '<div class="image-overlay"><a href="admin/includes/delete-img.php?id=' . $galname . '">Delete</a></div>';}?>
    </div>
    <div class="image-info">
        <a href="gallery.php?id=<?php echo htmlentities($row['gallery'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>">&larr; Back to Gallery</a>
        <p class="desc"><? echo htmlentities($row['desc'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And the query with $id = $_GET['id'];:

```
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        id,
        url, 
        gallery,
        desc
    FROM images
    WHERE id = $id
";
```

The only changes that have been are the addition of the desc in the query and the added PHP to echo the description. My table has the extra column necessary and I don't see what has happened. It may just be a simple mistake but I can't see the error in the syntax. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`desc` is a keyword in SQL. Need to enclose it in quotes. i.e.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    url, 
    gallery,
    `desc`
FROM images
WHERE id = $id
```

Comment: All working now, thank you! Still tinkering with MySQL so I'll have to have a more in-depth look at things.

Answer (score 1):

The other option if you don't want to delimit your columns with backticks around your query is to supply an alias on the table, eg

```
SELECT  i.id,
        i.url, 
        i.gallery,
        i.desc
FROM    images i
WHERE   id = $id
```